# Should customer class have the different function or should i include it in account class in my UML class diagram of banking system?

Tags: uml, software, class, class-diagram

[image: This is the class diagram.]

Should i include the different functions of open account, close account , withdraw in the customer class(as shown in the picture) or should i include it in the account class

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: The picture is explanatory. I am asking that whether i should place the functions of the customer class (open account, close account, withdraw, deposit etc) in the account class.

Comment: Customer comes to the bank to perform various functions( open account, close account, withdraw etc) but i think these functions should belong to the account class.

Comment: Where's your journal and your ledger? Where's your facility for customers to have more than one account, or for an account to be shared by more than one customer? How do you express the accounts that belong to the bank itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Improvement of your diagram?

In your diagram, you have opted to put all the actions that a customer can do as operation in the `Customer` class.  This is a consistent approach.  But, keep in mind that:

- opening an account or taking a loan are actions need as well a bank to conclude the operation;
- deposits, withdrawals and closing need not only a bank but also an account to operate on.
- some kind of accounts do not allow withdrawals (they can only be closed).
- perhaps some people may make a deposit on an account without being the customer.

So if this is your design,  you need to add some operations to the bank and the account as well, so that a customer object can cooperat with these objects to get the things done. And you should clarify the arguments of each operation.

### Another approach?

One of the most important principle in software design is separation of concerns.  So what is the concern of `Customer`:  is it to maintain customer information ?  Is it to represent a customer in the user interface ?  The later does not seem a great idea.

Another approach would therefore be to view operations performed by a customer with the bank as a separate class `Transaction`.  This separate class can then be specialized into `OpenAccount` `CloseAccount` `Withdrawal`, etc...

`Transaction` would need `Account` to know about how to change state in case of withdrawal or deposit, and `Bank` to be able to create new accounts and new customers.

It is then easy to add new types of accounts and new types of transactions, without necessarily have to change the customer.

Comment: Oh thank you, so rather than including the operations in customer class, I'll make a separate transaction class for them.